# Creating a copy of local git repository on a remote server

Tags: git

I have cloned a project from a server using `git clone` and I now want to copy it (all branches) to another server so other people can start using it.  I guess I could simply copy the entire repository manually and then issue `git config --bool core.bare true` and delete everything but the `.git` folder but I don't think that qualifies as a 'bare' repository and I'm worried it might give me problems.

I was hoping I could create the new remote repository using `git init --bare` and simply push my local one to it but as I originally cloned my local copy from another server, the `origin` seems to be blocking me from doing this.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1. Create a fresh bare repository on the server:
   `git init --bare newrepo.git`
2. Add it as a remote in your local repo:
   `git remote add newrepo git://user@server.com/newrepo.git`
3. `git push newrepo master` to push a particular branch, or
   `git push --all newrepo` to push all branches

Comment: `git push --all newrepo` ought to do it.

Comment: noob question: I did all this and I pushed to the remote successfully. however when I check the /newrepo.git on the server, I don't see the files. Anyone know where the files are?

Comment: @orane : this is because the repo was initialized with the `--bare` option. without this option, the code is extracted and a `.git` folder is created, containing the repository data. what you see after this command is just the repository data, without the extracted code.

Answer (score 13):

Another way is (as you wished):

```
git clone --bare /path/to/repo newrepo.git
```